# node ncp filter not working

Tags: node.js, copy, filesystems

I am trying to filter files through node [ncp library](https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp) but it its filter is not working.
Once the filter gets false return it breaks the whole copying process

```
   ncp(source, destination, options, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error("backup error:", err);

            }
            console.log("Backup of done!');


        });

 var options = {

           filter: function (file) {
                console.log("copying file:", file);

                var res = file.toString().indexOf("\\testdrive") !== -1;
                console.log("res:", res);

                return !res;

            },
            //filter: new RegExp("\\testdrive"),//Or RegEx intance
        };
```

So once the filter function or RegEx instance gets false result the whole copy break

> options.filter - a RegExp instance, against which each file name is tested to determine whether to copy it or not, or a function taking single parameter: copied file name, returning true or false, determining whether to copy file or not.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

I'm currently facing the same issue. As soon as the RegExp I use to filter tests to false, ncp silently crashes.

Comment: Since ncp is not maintained anymore I switched to [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) `copy()` which also [supports filters](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/blob/HEAD/docs/copy.md)

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution:
Seems like the filter RegExp/function will not only be called for the filenames that ncp is supposed to copy, but also for the foldernames.
The first foldername it filters is apparently the one you passed to ncp as source. And if that fails, ncp just stops copying anything in that folder.

See: https://github.com/AvianFlu/ncp/issues/130

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Thanks for the hint adiga. I edited my answer to be an actual answer, since I just found the solution.

Answer (score 0):

For those coming late to the party (like me):

`ncp` traverse dir tree in a way that directory full paths are subjected to filter as well,  on top of that, source directory itself is tested as well. In my case I wanted to copy bunch (lets call them `one.svg, zwei.svg, tres.svg`) of SVG files from single level directory called `images`, which resulted in following code:

```
ncp(srcImages, outImages, { filter: /.*(images|one\.svg|zwei\.svg|tres\.svg)$/ }, err => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log('done!')
});
```

PS: please note that there is `$` on the end of the regex meaning that we try to match end of the string

Comment: The dots before the filetypes should be escaped.